# When was an image of an apple first used to promote the APL language

Tags: history, programming, apl

The APL community is contemplating the adoption of [a common logo](https://apl.wiki/APL_logo) but some are worried about trouble from Apple lawyers. Now, IBM and others have been using apple motifs in promoting APL for a long time, but how long exactly? Maybe it can be shown to predate the lawsuit-happy Apple Computer Company?

- [Old IBM sticker](https://i2.wp.com/chelseatroy.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/i_like_apl_graphic-e1510606380891.jpg) apparently [from the '80s](https://en.todocoleccion.net/collectable-stickers/pegatina-i-like-apl-anos-80%7Ex213926063)
- [BYTE magazine from '77](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/File:BYTE_Cover_Aug_1977.png) with a striking resemblance to [Apple's logo at the time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Inc.#/media/File:Apple_first_logo.png).
- [A collection of APL apples](https://apl.wiki/Humour#Apples)

**When was an apple first used to promote APL?**

Comment: Wow! I'm a long time (ago) APL user and can't remember an _apple_ ever being used as a logo!  (And it would never ever have occurred to me to pronounce it "apple" instead of "A-P-L" - I wonder if I would have made the connection even if I saw it ...) Nice question!  (And the funny thing is, there never was an APL _keyboard_ with an apple symbol at the time even though they're ubiquitous now ...)  Here's a _secondary_ question:  Suppose they _had_ added an "apple" key to the APL keyboard (and type-ball): _which function would it have been mapped to_?  (existing or newly invented)

Comment: I used APL a bunch in the early 80's on my university IBM mainframe. I don't recall any material I got on APL that had an apple logo on it. Now I'm wondering where all my APL stuff went...

Comment: The IBM APL (apple) sticker - is it from the same time as teddybear (ie the VM mascot) and the turkey (MVS) ?   though i believe the teddybear and the turkey was choosen by the two user groups.

Comment: @StefanSkoglund I've added a link to a claim that it is form the '80s.

Comment: “Maybe it can be shown to predate the lawsuit-happy Apple Computer Company?” The thing about [prior art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_art) and [precedent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precedent), which is what your question implies, is it means that that the logo would have had to have been officially and commonly used in the past. Your examples are interesting, but they seem to be fan-made/hobby user creations. I mean the [BSD Daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSD_Daemon) was established since 1976 as an official mascot. An Apple being used by APL seems to be a cute novelty.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Thank you for that remark. Yeah, it'll probably be wisest to stick with a non-apple logo.

Comment: I think Apple would have a good case. The Apple logo is a registered trademark of Apple Inc. Prior art etc doesn't matter where registered trademarks are concerned. What does matter is that, if you have a trademark, you have to defend it or it could be revoked. 

Furthermore, it most certainly could be confusing. People who don't know about APL might assume it has something to do with Apple. So yes, APL should keep away from it to avoid legal battles they might lose.

Comment: @JeremyP While I agree with the conclusion, "if you have a trademark, you have to defend it or it could be revoked" is an [oversimplification](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2013/11/trademark-law-does-not-require-companies-tirelessly-censor-internet).

Comment: Can I suggest another way to deal with this: APL can also be interpreted as “Ape-L.” Knowing that, someone can just come up with some witty logo based around the idea of “Ape-L”; an Ape associated with the letter “L.”

Comment: @ssokolow Accepted but there are limited characters in a comment. My main point is that I think Apple would have a legitimate case if another computer technology oriented organisation started using an Apple as its trademark. People are likely to believe such an organisation is related to Apple.

Comment: @JeremyP No argument there. I just think it's important that people be aware.

Answer (score -2):

I think you may be confused.

The APL language predates even the Apple I computer by at least 7-8 years.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(programming_language)

This Application Programming Language was used on IBM360 mainframes in the 1960's and continues today.

Its longevity is much like FORTRAN and COBOL in that its necessity is required from legacy applications written for banking/government and other heavy industry where they don't want to mess with something that isn't outright broken.

For Apple Computer, Inc.: this would be the lineage of their use of an apple within their logo.

[image]

Comment: I think you may be confused. My question isn't whether APL (which by the way derives its name from a book called *A Programming Language*) pre-dates Apple Inc, but rather trying to establish "When was an apple first used to promote APL?".